# how to write class to do Database operation - spring integeration

Tags: spring-integration

i have a code

```html
<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway
  request-channel="nativeQlChannel" auto-startup="true"
  native-query="update Transactions t set t.transaction_Status = :transactionStatus where t.bank_Reference_Number = :bankReferenceNumber "
  entity-manager="entityManager" persist-mode="PERSIST" reply-channel="nativeQlChannelOne"
  use-payload-as-parameter-source="false">
```

it works fine , but as i need to execute insert operation on more than one table , and i am not able to do that by this configuration , 
how can i write code using spring integration JPA class like JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean , or any other so that i can perform DB operation in my java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it isn't JPA responsibility to worry about "more than one table".
It operates only with the entities as a high level abstraction.

Although yes, you can map your entity to several tables. Plus there is cascade insert when you have dependencies.

In addition that component supports `native-query/native-query` if you need more graceful control for your DB operation.

As for Java configuration correct: you should use `JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean` `@Bean` together with the `@ServiceActivator` to reach similar behavior.

You can find more samples in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/jpa.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_15).

Comment: i am using below code  Bean
 public JpaExecutor jpaExecutor() {
 JpaExecutor jpaExecutor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManagerFactory);
 jpaExecutor.setEntityClass(PartnerResponseDetails.class);
 jpaExecutor.setPersistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST);
 return jpaExecutor;
     }
 Bean
 ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "nativeQlChannel")
  public MessageHandler jpaOutbound() {
  JpaOutboundGateway adapter = new JpaOutboundGateway(jpaExecutor());
  adapter.setProducesReply(false);
  JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean beans;
return adapter;
    }

Comment: but i got exception Dispatcher has no subscribers , i am not able to find out where and how to use JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean, please give me some example how to use ?

Comment: Do you have `@EnableIntegration`? Plus why the reference manual example doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

i am able to fix it by using 
ExpressionEvaluatingParameterSourceFactory

ExpressionEvaluatingParameterSourceFactory paramFactory=new ExpressionEvaluatingParameterSourceFactory() ;
paramFactory.setParameters(paramList);

but i got exception 
WARN   - o.s.i.e.ExpressionUtils: Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanfactory

although it is not stopping any functionality . so i just ignored it.